# Already contains a definition for

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a class called `Assign` and

```
    private int SeatNumber;

    public Assign(int SeatNum)
    {
        SeatNumber = SeatNum;
    }

    public int SeatNumber
    {
        get { return SeatNumber; }
        set { SeatNumber = value; }

    }
```

I have no idea why I am getting the following error

> EThe type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Assign' already contains a definition for 'SeatNumber'

What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're declaring the same variable twice here.

```
private int SeatNumber;
public int SeatNumber
{
    get { return SeatNumber; }
    set { SeatNumber = value; }

}
```

That code defines the same variable twice. If you're using .net 3.0+, you can do auto-implemented properties like this with no `private int SeatNumber`:

```
public int SeatNumber
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

otherwise, you should do this:

```
private int SeatNumber_;
public int SeatNumber
{
    get { return SeatNumber_; }
    set { SeatNumber_ = value; }
}
```

Comment: That worked fine thanks a lot! Now im coming with an other issue. Along with SeatNumber i also have a "private boolean SeatStatus_ = false",using the same method for it as well. In my form.cs i have
"static int NumberOfSeats ;
 Assign [] AssignArray = new Assign[NumberOfSeats];" and "int RowIndex = Int32.Parse(this.textSeatNumber.Text) -1;" and if row is smaller than a value "AssignArray[RowIndex].SeatNumber = this.checkBookSeat.Checked;" but im getting an error of coverting bool to int!

Comment: sounds like you need to rename your boolean SeatStatus_ to something else so that it doesn't conflict with the int SeatStatus_ variable.

Answer (score 5):

You should make sure that the variable that backs the property has a different name. It is common to use camelCase for it:

```
private int seatNumber;

public Assign(int SeatNum)
{
    SeatNumber = SeatNum;
}

public int SeatNumber
{
    get { return seatNumber; }
    set { seatNumber = value; }
}
```

Moreover, in situations where the getter ans setter are trivial, starting with C# 3.0 you can use *automatic properties*, like this:

```
public int SeatNumber {get; set;}
```

This lets you remove the backing variable: the compiler will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 4):

The private and public variables can't have the same name, that is where the conflict is coming from. Do this:

```
private int _seatNumber;

public Assign(int SeatNum)
{
    SeatNumber = SeatNum;
}

public int SeatNumber
{
    get { return _seatNumber; }
    set { _seatNumber = value; }

}
```

The underscore notation is common for private variables.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you're basically assigning something to SeatNumber in the constructor and then doing it again in the property. When creating class fields in Visual Studio, type 'propfull' and hit the tab key twice. This will auto create the field and property for you.

For what it's worth, this is the generally accepted way to structure classes.

```
class Assign
   {
      //Fields
      private int _seatNumber;


      //Properties
      public int SeatNumber
      {
         get { return _seatNumber; }
         set { _seatNumber = value; }
      }

      //Overloaded Constructors
      public Assign(int sn)
      {
         SeatNumber = sn;
      }
      public Assign()
      {

      }

      //Methods 
      public void SomeMethod()
      {
         //insert code
      }
      public void SomeOtherMethod()
      {
         //insert code
      }

   }//END ASSIGN CLASS
```