# Cannot understand interface inheritance

Tags: c#

The following code give me error that

> Error 2   The type 'Series.AB' already contains a definition for 'B'

```
 interface IA
{
    void A();
}
interface IB
{
    void B();
}

interface IAB : IA, IB
{
    void A();
    void B();
}

class AB : IAB
{
    IA A;
    IB B;
    public AB(IA _a, IB _b)
    {
        A = _a;
        B = _b;
    }

    public void A()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void B()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I thought that I can use AB class instance as

> IA A = new AB(); Or IB B = new AB(); Or IAB ab = new AB();

i am not able to understand what happen here. please anyone describe why this exception occurs.

Comment: Posible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name

Comment: This error is unrelated to interface and inheritance really. You have a method and a field with the same names. `B` is the name of a field and a method (the same goes for `A`). That is not allowed.

Comment: The closest possible duplicate I found: [Already contains a definition for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770014/already-contains-a-definition-forget-set-method). In either question OP think it's something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can interfaces replace the need for multiple inheritance when have existing classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003285/how-can-interfaces-replace-the-need-for-multiple-inheritance-when-have-existing)

Comment: Interface IA is pointing and capable of refering only A() method ,similarly IB B() method .SO IAB ab should  work smoothly.A solid principle is that the type that is inheriting the interface must provide implementation in the entire inheritance chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Property Names to Something other than A and B as you have method names with same name. Also have default constructor in class AB.

```
class AB : IAB
{
    IA instanceA;
    IB instanceB;
    public AB(IA _a, IB _b)
    {
        instanceA = _a;
        instanceB = _b;
    }

    public void A()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void B()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```